# Accessing the parent of a QProcess

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I find myself in the following situation:
I have a simple Application *FIRST.app* which has a `MainWindow` class defined as follow:

```cpp
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();
private:
    QProcess* m_myself;
}
```

in which a pointer to a `QProcess` is defined.
In the constructor I then initialize `m_myself`

```cpp
m_myself = new QProcess(this);
```

passing the instance of the `MainWindow` as its parent.

Later in the code I then `start` a twin QtApplication *SECOND.app* which is supposed to do nothing but printing the `parent` in the QtConsole.

The code to start the *SECOND.app* is:

```cpp
m_myself->start("SECOND.app", QStringList(), QIODevice::ReadWrite);
```

*SECOND.app* is nothing but a `MainWindow` and in the constructor I would print the `parent` application as follow:

```cpp
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    qInfo() << qobject_cast<QDockWidget*>(this->parent());
}
```

but the console prints `QWidget(0x0)` a `nullptr`.

**EDIT:**

as pointed out by @Igor Tandetnik the reason is that:

> Each process has its own separate address space

So I took a look into the `QSharedMemory` class and I implemented [this example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcore-ipc-sharedmemory-example.html) into my code writing the instance of the `MainWindow` of *FIRST.app* into the shared memory

```cpp
void MainWindow::start()
{
...
    QDataStream out(&buffer);
    QObject * thisApp = this;

    out << thisApp;
...
}
```

and accessing it from *SECOND.app* as follows:

```cpp
 QObject* parentApp;
 QBuffer buffer;
 QDataStream in(&buffer);
 sharedMemory.lock();
 buffer.setData((char*)sharedMemory.constData(),
 sharedMemory.size());
 buffer.open(QBuffer::ReadOnly);
 in >> parentApp;
```

but here I get an error:

```
error: invalid operands to binary expression ('QDataStream' and 'QObject *')
```

the Qt official example worked with a `QImage`, but how can I share a `QObject` over a shared memory slot?

Thanks!

Comment: You don't. Each process has its own separate address space; even if you somehow managed to transfer an address from one process to another, it'd be meaningless there. There are many mechanisms for [interprocess communication](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/ipc.html), but passing pointers across process boundary is not one of them.

Comment: thank you for your quick reply...but then why would you pass an instance of a class as an argument of QProcess?

Comment: For [memory management](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/objecttrees.html). `QProcess` is derived from `QObject`, and the `parent` pointer just gets passed along to `QObject` constructor; it has no special meaning for process management. When `MainWindow` instance is destroyed, it'd automatically delete the `QProcess` object, thanks to this parent/child relationship. Observe how you have `m_myself = new QProcess(this)` but likely don't have `delete m_myself;` - that's where the magic of `QObject` ownership comes in.